# Windows system call issue in W2K8

Tags: windows

I am having a problem with windows system function “EnumProcessModules()” that is defined in psapi.dll. In our component we use this function to retrieve modules in a specified process. This function is working well as long as we run the program on a 32-bit OS. However, this function fails when we run the program on a 64-bit OS (e.g. W2K8 R2).  As you all know we are targeting Clay and Brick on W2K8 R2s. This is a known problem as per the following discussion in MSDN. One work around that was suggested in that thread is to compile the code as 64-bit. To us that is not an option, at least not yet. Do you have any suggestions? Any pointers/suggestions/ideas will be appreciated.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification/thread/c7d7e3fe-f8e5-49c3-a16f-8e3dec5e8cf8/

Answer (score 1):

If your existing code must continue being compiled as 32-bit, one possibility would be to create a small 64-bit executable that enumerates the processes via [EnumProcessModulesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682633.aspx). The 32-bit process could spawn the 64-bit process when necessary to do that work.  Then use some kind of IPC to transfer the information back to the 32-bit process.  Depending on what is needed, that part could be as low tech as writing a file to disk and reading it from the first process (or pipes, shared memory, sockets, etc.).